# AngularJS pattern for persisting record selection through multiple asynchronous calls?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

We're working on CRUD patterns for a fairly large application. One common UI pattern we're using to define a one-to-many relationship where a record is associated by checkbox. The challenge is to persist selections (checked/unchecked) through asynchronous calls (search/sort) that refresh the record list (and the associated ng-model). I'd like to hear from more advanced AngularJS users (I'm a noob) what's considered a best practice for this? Any feedback is appreciated!

[image]

**EDIT**

[Here's a working plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/TzaHuWBcRM9fIHD3X23Q?p=preview) showing how I'd most likely tackle this with my current understanding of Angular. Please let me know if you have a better approach!

Comment: This sounds like a "can you program this for me" type of question, which is not a type that is acceptable on SO. Either show what you tried so far and what problem you're experiencing or expect this question to be closed pretty soon.

Comment: My first inclination is to create a `$scope.selectedUsers = []` and populate it when checking/unchecking items from the list, but it seems a bit sloppy?

Comment: I think that's probably the easiest way to approach it, Brian. Then set the selected state for each row by checking for presence in selectedUsers. You'll end up with no-longer-valid users in selectedUsers, if someone selected is removed from the list. That's fine...unless a later call puts them back, and they're suddenly selected again. (There's an alternate possibility that retains the use of ng-model, but I'd want to experiment with it before I recommended it. Have a fiddle?)

Comment: Thanks@SMcCrohan, I'm very curious about the ng-model approach. I was really hoping there would be a way to leverage it. I'll put a fiddle together ASAP and post it.

Comment: I love your picture. Is there any app to make it ? BTW, if you didn't, take a look at http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/angularjs/#/ Sources may be helpful

Comment: Thanks @Utopik, I can't take credit for the image. I came across it somewhere years ago. Don't even remember where to be honest :) Thanks for the link, I'll give it a look!

Comment: @SMcCrohan, here's a plunk with my first attempt if you find time to try leveraging ng-model... http://plnkr.co/edit/TzaHuWBcRM9fIHD3X23Q?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

I think u could maintain a separate collection of selected names. So the next time you filter the list, you just need to lookup in the collection in order to keep the item selected. That you can do by binding some variable (arrSelected) in the controller or you can create a separate service also.

Comment: I like the service approach. It would be great to alternatively store the selections in local storage to prevent a loss in case of a page refresh. The service approach would make that very portable. Thanks!

Comment: Make the collection a hash and you have 0 lookup time/overhead: `ng-model="selectedItems[item.id]"`

Comment: Yep, that's what I was thinking as well. Do still need to watch out for the selection state of items that are removed from the list but then readded.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a filter instead of refetching. Of course this really depends on how many items you plan on having, but I've had success filtering a nested JSON object with around 5000 items.

Here is the full plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/l4jYgt0LjRoP2H0YuTIT?p=preview

Highlights:
In **index.html** for your repeat you add | filter

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:userFilter">
```

In **script.js** we add the filter function and a $scope variable to hold the filtered letter:

```
$scope.filteredLetter
$scope.userFilter = function (elem) {
  if (elem.name.lastIndexOf($scope.filteredLetter, 0) === 0 || $scope.filteredLetter == '') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

As a bonus I added in ng-class to show which letter was highlighted.

Pretty simple code but this gives you full persistence now even as people change things. You can even experiment now with adding a `<input>` tag with an **ng-model** binding to say **$scope.filteredName**. Then all you need to do is add the JS to the filter to do a deeper filter for part of the name.

Comment: I like this approach, thanks! Question. You mention getting acceptable performance filtering 5000 records? How many "columns" were you looking at in that scenario? Have you noticed at what point the performance starts to take a hit?

Comment: Hi Brian, I'm using around 8 data points for my last level. I should have mentioned that this is a tree structure, so probably even more complicated that what you're doing. Because my system has a fixed set of points (Exercises) I haven't really bothered testing much further. That being said for your scenario I imagine you could just duplicate your user table a few times to test it out.